# Keeping a Key and Object property the same

Tags: java

I create instances of Person, and put them in a `Map<String, Person>`. The key of the map entry is the same as the name property of the Person. Since the name can be changed, how can I keep both the key of the map and the property of the person the same?

```
public class Person{

    private String name;

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Should I even use a Map in this case? Are there any better ways of doing this using for example a List?

Edit:
What I need can be explained:
Something similar to a List. Only that the List.get() function does not return by index ID, but by an object's property value. List cannot contain more than one object with this value.

Comment: The closest thing to what you want is to remove the `Person` from the `Map` when their name is changed and reinsert them with the new name.

Comment: There are many ways to do what you want, usually implementation depends on some specific aspects, for example, if you will have millions of such records, then List would be a bad idea since every time you would be looking for a person you would need to traverse a List, etc. So you need to be more specific.

Comment: I guess it will have around 500-1000 records. Don't you think I can iterate over a List from another method to find the Person with that name?

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet would be to keep a map of some user I'd to the person, name is not a good key because as you have mentioned it can change but if YOU generate the key then it is always known and cannot be changed by outside input.

Why do you have to store the people in a map(or any data structure) in the first case?

I'm really not sure on the details but you could store all you're people in an array and do a look up by name every time but this is going to cause hella performance problems because you are iterating over this list to find the item.

```
 public class Person{
     private static int count = 0;
     private string name;
     private int ID;
     public Person(string name){
         this.id =++count;
         this.name = name;
     }
      //the rest of your code;

      public Int GetId(){
         return this.ID;
      }
 }
```

This may not be ideal because you are limited to the number of people by the max size of an int.

This way is also very good because now you don't have to worry about names being unique since you are keying off the id of the person.

If you really have to do a look up by name then you will either a) have to keep an instance of the map and update it every time set name is called in person or keep all the people in an array and do a look up when you want to get to them.

Comment: I need to be able to look them up by their unique name/ID. Also, other parts of the program needs to get this name/ID from the object itself.

Comment: Thank you, I think I am a bit closer to finding what I need now.